# IPv4-prefix notation range in Kusto

Tags: kql

How can I ignore all the results with Name: Test1 having 10.X.X.X IPs? I still need Test2 and Test8 in the results.

[image]

I tried

```
| where Name == "Test1" or ipv4_is_in_range(IPAddress, "10.0.0.0/8") == false
```

I also tried `ipv4_is_in_any_range()` but that's not recognized but this didn't work. Would appreciate some assistance here. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> *How can I ignore all the results with Name: `Test1` having `10.X.X.X` IPs? I still need Test2 and Test8 in the results.*

If I understand your intention correctly, this should work:

```
| where not(Name == "Test1" and IPAddress startswith "10.")
```